# create function about buttons click, buttons created by loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

this image is my app `post detail` page
this app is service about booksaling so user can post about booksale

[image]

the feature is

- `userA` create a post (he want sale book1, book2, book3)
- if book2 was sold out `userA` should click `sold out button`
- when `sold out button` clicked, `sold out` will converted `click cancel` and `strike` line will added book2 (like <strike>book2(2222원)</strike>)

so i decide using js+ jquery

here's my js code

```
(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){
    //$book_list_num is received number of books
    //book1, book2, book3//$book_list_num = 3 
    $book_list_num = $("div").data("listNum");

    console.log($book_list_num);

    var $cancel_button = []

    for(i=1; i<= parseInt($book_list_num); i++){

        //$cancel_button[0]=#btn1,
        //$cancel_button[1]=#btn2,
        //$cancel_button[2]=#btn3
        $cancel_button[$cancel_button.length] = $("#btn"+i);


        $cancel_button[i].on('click', function(event){
           //test alert
           alert(i)
        });
    };
});

})();
```

but web browser console show error

```
cancelbutton.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

I can not understand why js can't read `on`method
please somebody help me

Comment: @Rayon wont help that's a jQuery already if exists

Comment: @Rayon - the elements in the `$cancel_button` array are already jQuery objects. But OP hasn't allowed for array indices being zero-based.

Comment: @nnnnnn — Ooh yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying adding `click` event listener in `for` loop can you please try following code:

```
$("[id^=btn]").on('click', function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var number = id.replace("btn", "");
    //test alert
    alert(number)
});
```

Here we are attaching `click` handler for all the DOM elements whose `id` starts with `"btn"`. Hope it will help you a bit.

Comment: *"You can not put your click event handler in for loop."* - Why not?

Comment: sorry @nnnnnn. Actually i wanted to recommend another way of doing it. Updated the wording.

Comment: @vijayP YOU SOLVED MY TERRIBLE PROBLEM THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! I'm so happy about your fantasic solution! I was almost crazy because `function + loop in js` is so hard to me,,, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It comes from here:

```
$cancel_button[i].on('click', function(event){
   //test alert
   alert(i)
})
```

Change to:

```
for(var i=0,l = parseInt($book_list_num);i<l; i++){

    //$cancel_button[0]=#btn1,
    //$cancel_button[1]=#btn2,
    //$cancel_button[2]=#btn3
    $cancel_button[i] = $("#btn"+(i+1));


    $cancel_button[i].on('click', function(event){
       //test alert
       alert(i)
    });
};
```

Comment: You've spotted the problem, but more explanation explaining the subtle changes you've made would be nice. (Of course, having fixed this the OP is about to have another problem, with the alert displaying the same value for every item.)